# How can I add transform style to always work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a "button" and after click I add transform style.
But if I click second time this style don't work, because it already has this class.

How do I change this?

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('btn_transform');
});
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 80px;
  background-color: green;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  margin: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn_transform {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn"></button>
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove class? Is it difficult?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".btn").mouseup(function() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".btn").removeClass('btn_transform');
  }, 300);

});


$(".btn").mousedown(function() {

  $(this).addClass('btn_transform');

});
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 80px;
  background-color: green;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  margin: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn_transform {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn"></button>
```

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('btn_transform');
});
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 80px;
  background-color: green;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  margin: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn_transform {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn"></button>
```

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing and adding the class in a single block will not work. A possible solution is removing the class and adding it later using `setTimeout` with a very short time:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
var self = this;
$(this).removeClass('btn_transform');
setTimeout(
function(){$(self).addClass('btn_transform')}
, 10);
});
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 80px;
  background-color: green;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  margin: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn_transform {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn"></button>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the transitionend event ?